# Ruby search through multidimensional array and remove element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multidimensional-array

Can anyone help me with this? This is my problem:
  I need to search through a three or four dimensional array and remove elements from it.

Note: the order must be preserved

Example array:

```
[[["tard_cat", "pusheen_cat"], ["boo_dog"]]]
```

I want to remove elements with the substring 'cat'. So the expected result would be:

```
[[[], ["boo_dog"]]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do:

```
def deep_remove!(text, array)
  array.delete_if do |value|
    case value
    when String
      value.include? text
    when Array
      deep_remove!(text, value)
      false
    else
      false
    end
  end
end

array = [[["tard_cat", "pusheen_cat"], ["boo_dog"]]]
deep_remove!('cat', array)
```

Comment: +1.. I like your method..

Comment: Hmm my comment was deleted. Anyway I'll post it again. Thank you so much for this solution. This is perfect! I appreciate all your help :)